# SwingerWorker for Character Animation in an Applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet, swingworker

With my current code I have a character that loads in a sprite sheet for the animation. My problem arises when I run the code. The game runs fine except that the player is loading/cycling sprites way too fast. I believe this stems from the overall game timing/update. I should state that the game is working through an applet. I gathered some information on SwingerWorkers, but I don't know how to manipulate it to my needs. If someone could take a look at my code and let me know what I could do, I'd appreciate it.

Player constructor:

```
public Player(Image pic, ImageObserver IO){

    positionX=200;
    positionY=200;
    destinationX=(int)positionX;
    destinationY=(int)positionY;
    speed = 2.3;

    girlImage=pic;
    this.io=IO;
    width=120;
    height=100;
    //this.playerImage=playerImage;

    // Gets each sprite
    BufferedImage img = createImage();

    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
            girlAll[j][i] = girl[j].getSubimage(imgWidth*i, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        }//end of for   
    }//end of for
}

    // Image loader
private BufferedImage createImage(){
    //BufferedImage bufferedImage;
    try {
        girl[0] = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/blutuu/Documents/Marlin/UD/Workspace S13/MoD/src/female_player_northeast_walk.png"));
        girl[1] = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/blutuu/Documents/Marlin/UD/Workspace S13/MoD/src/female_player_northwest.png"));
        girl[2] = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/blutuu/Documents/Marlin/UD/Workspace S13/MoD/src/female_player_southeast.png"));
        girl[3] = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/blutuu/Documents/Marlin/UD/Workspace S13/MoD/src/female_player_southwest.png"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Draw method:

```
public void draw(Graphics g){
    //g.drawImage(girlImage, (int)positionX,(int) positionY,io);

    picNum = (picNum + 1) % frameCount;
    pics = girlAll[x];
    if (x==0)
        g.drawImage(pics[picNum], (int) (positionX), (int) (positionY), io);
    if (x==1)
        g.drawImage(pics[picNum], (int) (positionX), (int) (positionY), io);
    if (x==2)
        g.drawImage(pics[picNum], (int) (positionX), (int) (positionY), io);
    if (x==3)
        g.drawImage(pics[picNum], (int) (positionX), (int) (positionY), io);
}
```

SwingWorker attempt:

```
SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<BufferedImage[], Void>() {

    public BufferedImage[] doInBackground(){
        //BufferedImage bufferedImage;
        try {
            girl[0] = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/blutuu/Documents/Marlin/UD/Workspace S13/MoD/src/female_player_northeast_walk.png"));
            girl[1] = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/blutuu/Documents/Marlin/UD/Workspace S13/MoD/src/female_player_northwest.png"));
            girl[2] = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/blutuu/Documents/Marlin/UD/Workspace S13/MoD/src/female_player_southeast.png"));
            girl[3] = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/blutuu/Documents/Marlin/UD/Workspace S13/MoD/src/female_player_southwest.png"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void loadImg() {

        doInBackground();

        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
                girlAll[j][i] = girl[j].getSubimage(imgWidth*i, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            }//end of for   
        }//end of for

    }

};

}
```

Runs game (from 'Game' class):

```
public void init(){
    //Execute a job on the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating this applet's GUI.
    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.err.println("createGUI didn't successfully complete");
    }       

}
```

Thread handling:

```
private void gameStuff(){
    try {Thread.sleep(sleepTime);}
    catch (InterruptedException e) {}

    mouseClicked=false;
}
```

Game rendering:

```
public void update (Graphics g)
{
//      initialize buffer
    if (dbImage == null)
    {
        dbImage = createImage (this.getSize().width,    this.getSize().height);
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics ();

    }

//      clear screen in background
    dbg.setColor (getBackground ());
    dbg.fillRect (0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);

//      draw elements in background
    //dbg.setColor (getForeground());
    paint (dbg);

//      draw image on the screen
    g.drawImage (dbImage, 0, 0, this);

}
```

Another rendering method:

```
private void hud(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.fillRect(300, 0, 500, 80);
    g.fillRect(200, 0, 100, 80);

    //SHOVEL IMAGE AND BUTTON
    g.drawImage(shovelImage,      520,0,this);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(520, 0, 60, 80);//show boundaries
    if(mouseClicked && new Rectangle(520, 0, 60, 80).contains(mx,my))
        toolSelected=1; //sets tool selected to shovel

    //ROCKS IMAGE AND BUTTON
    g.drawImage(rocksImage,       600,0, this);
    g.drawRect(600, 0, 60, 80);//show boundaries
    if(mouseClicked && new Rectangle(600, 0, 60, 80).contains(mx,my))
        toolSelected=2; //sets tool selected to shovel

    //JACKHAMMER IMAGE AND BUTTON
    g.drawImage(jackHammerImage,  680,0, this);
    g.drawRect(680, 0, 60, 80);//show boundaries
    if(mouseClicked && new Rectangle(680, 0, 60, 80).contains(mx,my))
        toolSelected=3; //sets tool selected to shovel

    if(timer.getAngle()<360){
    timer.draw(g);
    }
    if(timer.getAngle()==360){
        raining=true;
        timer.reset();
        addDrops();
        roundNum++;
        puddles();

    }
    drawProgressBar(g);

    if(toolSelected == 1)
    {
        Message = "Native Delaware plants";
        Message2 = "are good";
    }
    else if(toolSelected == 2)
    {
        Message = "Rocks with Runoff";
        Message2 = " ";
    }
    else if(toolSelected == 3)
    {
        Message = "Permeated Driveways";
        Message2 = "help with excesse water";
    }
    else{
        Message = "Play On";
        Message2 = " ";
    }
    g.drawString("Round "+roundNum, 350, 30);
    g.drawString(Message, 205, 40);
    g.drawString(Message2, 205, 55);

    drawTiles(g);

}
```

Comment: How are you controlling the timing?  How is the character rendered to the screen?

Comment: Agree -- I don't see any game control loop anywhere in your code.

Comment: I added some code which I believe handles timing.

Comment: Your latest code, the bit with the `Thread.sleep(...)` does nothing useful, and could be quite dangerous if called on the Swing event thread since you'll never want to call `Thread.sleep(...)` on that thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Before using a SwingWorker, if all you want to do is a time-controlled simple game loop, use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead.
- If I were swapping sprite images, I'd consider swapping Icons in a JLabel as the easiest first thing I'd try.
- Don't override `update(Graphics g)` for Swing GUI's. That was used for AWT, but for Swing is not appropriate. The graphics tutorials will tell you this.
- Don't call `paint(...)` or `paintComponent(...)` directly. For more details, check out the [basic Swing drawing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and also [a more advanced article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) on Painting in AWT and Swing.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SpriteAnimationApplet extends JApplet {
   private static final String SPRITE_SHEET_SPEC = "http://www.funorb.com/img/images/game/"
         + "central/dev_diary/sprite_sheet_full.gif";
   private static final int SPRITE_ROWS = 8; // an 8 x 8 sprite sheet

   @Override
   public void init() {
      try {
         final Icon[] icons = SpriteIO.getSprites(SPRITE_SHEET_SPEC, SPRITE_ROWS);
         SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               SpriteAnimationPanel spritePanel = new SpriteAnimationPanel(icons);
               getContentPane().add(spritePanel);
               spritePanel.startAnimation();
            }
         });
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(-1);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(-1);
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(-1);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(-1);
      }
   }

}

class SpriteIO {
   public static Icon[] getSprites(String spriteSheetSpec, int spriteRows)
         throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
      Icon[] icons = new Icon[spriteRows * spriteRows];
      URL spriteSheetUrl = new URL(spriteSheetSpec);
      BufferedImage spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(spriteSheetUrl);
      double wD = (double) spriteSheet.getWidth() / spriteRows;
      double hD = (double) spriteSheet.getHeight() / spriteRows;
      int w = (int) wD;
      int h = (int) hD;
      for (int i = 0; i < spriteRows; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < spriteRows; j++) {
            int x = (int) (i * wD);
            int y = (int) (j * hD);
            BufferedImage img = spriteSheet.getSubimage(x, y, w, h);

            icons[j * spriteRows + i] = new ImageIcon(img);
         }
      }
      return icons;
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class SpriteAnimationPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 200;
   private Icon[] icons;
   private JLabel animationLabel = new JLabel();

   public SpriteAnimationPanel(Icon[] icons) {
      this.icons = icons;
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(animationLabel );
   }

   public void startAnimation() {
      Timer spriteTimer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
         private int iconIndex = 0;

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            animationLabel.setIcon(icons[iconIndex]);
            iconIndex++;
            iconIndex %= icons.length;
         }
      });
      spriteTimer.start();
   }
}
```

Comment: @blutuu: did you look at my code before asking this? The reason I ask is because my code above ***is*** an applet!

Comment: Note this would only work in a sand-boxed or 'no security manager' applet given it is attempting to reach across domains in the value of `SPRITE_SHEET_SPEC`.  This is one of the things that makes making an SSCCE for an applet tougher.  BTW - OP, obviously that URL can be changed, and if it points to the 'home server' the code will run OK when sand-boxed.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: thanks for the update. One more reason why I hate applets.

Comment: Re. applets.  I was keeping a list.  After filling a few A3 pages, I don't keep a list anymore..

Comment: Sorry I seen a JFrame extension and it threw me off. Now I know. I'll study some more.

Comment: @blutuu: please tell me where the JFrame extended class is located. I seriously can't remember the last time I wrote a class that extends JFrame, although I use JFrames a lot.

Comment: My mistake, it was a JPanel.

Comment: I actually found a way to slow my character animation and it's quite trivial. In the draw method, I incremented a `counter` variable which, when it reaches a certain number, updates the `picNum` variable. It works as a delay in the update process and it solves my short term problems. Nonetheless, I'll pick this as the answer as it has a much more general premise. Thanks again for your help.